# Как привязать скролл страницы к изображению в галерее?

Tags: jquery

Суть: нажимаю на миниатюру, открывается модальное окно с полным изображением. Как сделать, чтоб если изображение полностью помещается на экране (не вылазит за границы окна), то скролл страницы справа исчезал. А если изображение больше окна по вертикали, то скрол появлялся, но прокручивал не страницу, а модальное окно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант.

- Для body делаем `height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow:hidden`.
- А для модального окна `height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow:auto`.

Естественно, такое только когда модальное окно открыто. Когда оно закрыто, пусть будут ваши обычные стили.

Comment: попробуем-с